# Angular Horizontal Timeline CodeHouse

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use the Horizontal Timeline (https://codyhouse.co/gem/horizontal-timeline/) in my project with angular, 
I'm trying to make a directive to control the timeline but I'm having problems with the arrival of the data to the frontend , where the timeline does not recognize me as my date validates data, someone has had this kind of problem before?

greetings !

https://plnkr.co/edit/gRqYx2SgS7srkPbqqOAT?p=preview

```
angular.module("MyApp",[])
   .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.hola = "Hola Mundo";
    $scope.data =
     [
         {
             "date": "16/01/2014",
            "title": "Horizontal Timeline",
        "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium officia, fugit recusandae ipsa, quia velit nulla adipisci? Consequuntur aspernatur at, eaque hic repellendus sit dicta consequatur quae, ut harum ipsam molestias maxime non nisi reiciendis eligendi! Doloremque quia pariatur harum ea amet quibusdam quisquam, quae, temporibus dolores porro doloribus."
    },
    {
        "date": "18/02/2014",
        "title": "Title Here",
        "content": "Illum praesentium officia, fugit recusandae ipsa, quia velit nulla adipisci? Consequuntur aspernatur at, eaque hic repellendus sit dicta consequatur quae, ut harum ipsam molestias maxime non nisi reiciendis eligendi! Doloremque quia pariatur harum ea amet quibusdam quisquam, quae, temporibus dolores porro doloribus."
    },
    {
        "date": "02/03/2014",
        "title": "Horizontal Timeline Angular",
        "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium officia, fugit recusandae ipsa, quia velit nulla adipisci? Consequuntur aspernatur at, eaque hic repellendus sit dicta consequatur quae, ut harum ipsam molestias maxime non nisi reiciendis eligendi! Doloremque quia pariatur harum ea amet quibusdam quisquam, quae, temporibus dolores porro doloribus."
    },
    {
        "date": "25/03/2014",
        "title": "Test Horizontal Timeline",
        "content": "Consequuntur aspernatur at, eaque hic repellendus sit dicta consequatur quae, ut harum ipsam molestias maxime non nisi reiciendis eligendi! Doloremque quia pariatur harum ea amet quibusdam quisquam, quae, temporibus dolores porro doloribus."
    },

];

  })
   .directive('timeline', function($timeout){
     return{
       restrict: 'A',
       scope: { data: '=data' },
       templateUrl: "HorizontalTimeline.html",
     };
   });
```

Comment: Did u finish this ? i am having similar issues

Comment: Unfortunately not my friend...